# Visual studio team services - Octopus does not work after agent update to version 2

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, octopus-deploy

**Background:**

We are using the VSTS to build and Octopus integration to deploy our product. The Octopus step is configured as follows,

[image]

**Issue**

Today VSTS Build was throwing following error,

> No supported agent found in pool Default. All agents in this pool are
>   using a version that is deprecated. Migrate to the latest 2.x version
>   of agent. For more information, see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851067

As a result, the Agent was updated to the latest version, 
After the update the octopus step stopped working with following error,

[image]

Then issue seems to be the environment variables are not replaced in the step.

I would like to know if there is a work around to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is **2.*** version available, so you can delete the old one and add the new one.

Secondly, use `$(Build.BuildNumber)` instead in Package Version input box, also for Output path: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't see the option to add the 2.* it only shows 1.*. Yes, using $(Build.BuildNumber) and $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) works.